# Use Vue.js as realtime update with low latency

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, websocket, vue.js

I am creating a stock exchanger website with php using laravel frame work and MYSQL to solve realtime updating issue, I was thinking to use Vue.js but the problem is, if I setTimeOut 500 for getting latest data and there be more than 10,000 user in the exchange page it means every second I am sending 20,000 query to database to get all the data for each user.
My question is, is there any better way? For example I just update one file, and those users only load that file instead of using 20,000 MYSQL query every second?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. It's called `websockets`. Take a look into those.

Comment: RethinkDb was developed to solve this problem.

Comment: Websockets or Caching and maybe a combination of those will help you.

Comment: You could also try Firebase